# How do I make the login usernames and passwords case sensitive

Tags: vba

I want to make the Login Username and Passwords case sensitive. I have 2 levels of login. 1 is hardcoded "Developer" its its associated password is "-Brty4587TRYIN" and the other is table Lookup. I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. I can tinker program but that's all I am. My code is below.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmdLogin_ClickErr
    
    If Len(Me.txtUserName) = 9 And Len(Me.txtPassword) = 14 Then
        TempVars.Add "UserName", "Developer"
        TempVars.Add "Password", "-Brty4587TRYIN"
        TempVars.Add "Admin", "-1"

    Else
      Dim rs As Recordset
      Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From TLKPeople Where Username = '" & Me.txtUserName & "' And [Password] = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
      If Not rs.EOF Then
          TempVars.Add "UserName", rs!UserName.Value
          TempVars.Add "Password", rs!Password.Value
          TempVars.Add "Admin", rs!Admin.Value
          TempVars.Add "ReadOnly", rs!ReadOnly.Value
          TempVars.Add "StdUser", rs!STDUser.Value
          TempVars.Add "OpsUser", rs!OpsUser.Value
      Else
          MsgBox "Your login as failed!", vbOKOnly, "Login Failed"
          Exit Sub
      End If
      rs.Close
      Set rs = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Nz(TempVars!UserName, 0) = "Developer" Then
         DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
    End If
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "MenuMain"
    DoEvents

Exit Sub
    
cmdLogin_ClickErr:
    MsgBox ("Err: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StrComp`:

```vb
"Select * From TLKPeople Where StrComp(Username, '" & Me!txtUserName.Value & "', 0) = 0 And StrComp([Password], '" & Me!txtPassword.Value & "', 0) = 0"
```

and:

```vb
If StrComp(Nz(TempVars!UserName), "Developer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks mate
I'll give it a try shortly and accept it once I try it.

Comment: I'm getting an error
Compile Error Sub or Function not defined.
me.txtpassowrd is highlighted?

Comment: Try with explicit syntax. See edited answer, please.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, I don't know what you mean, can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks Mate, i sorta got it working, I am close now.